# Stand alone ruby gem that can be installed in server

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I want to write a ruby gem which will act as a monitoring tool for kannel. download and install in server and start a small worker or something.How i can make this? Iam not asking the script for kannel monitoring but how to make a tool .

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you elaborate on what you have tried? And about what tools you have used? E.g. Gemcutter, Jeweler for creating gems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RailsCasts has a decent episode on making a gem](http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler) with [Bundler](http://bundler.io).

Bundler will handle the structure, you just need to write your application.  Libraries in the `/lib` directory, binaries (or scripts you want to be executable) in `/bin`.  Pretty simple!

Comment: how to make it installable in local and run as a background task

Comment: Install locally: `gem install gem_name` if it's deployed somewhere accessible.  Run as a background task depends on the server, it's just another script that can be run.